# How to use SendTweetWithMedia with TweetSharp?

Tags: c#, vb.net, twitter

So I'm trying to use TweetSharp in VB.NET 2012 with C# to post a tweet with a image.

I found the code example of how to do it:

```
service.SendTweetWithMedia(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions 
{ 
     Status = "message", 
     Images = dictionary 
}
);
```

However I'm not sure how to create the "dictionary" with the picture stream.

I tried this:

```
Dictionary<string, Stream> imageDict = new Dictionary<string, Stream>();
```

then referenced that later:

```
Images = imageDict
```

But it gives the error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COHcf.png)

Anyone have any ideas of how this is supposed to work?

Another block of code I found and tried is:

```
    using (var stream = new FileStream("Image.jpg", FileMode.Open))
    {
        var result = tservice.SendTweetWithMedia(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions
        {
            Status = "Message",
            Images = new Dictionary<string, Stream> { { "john", stream } }
        });
        lblResult.Text = result.Text.ToString();
    }
```

But it gives the same error about "FileStream".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the System.IO namespace, this is why you receive this error in the image you posted.

Here is an example:

```
var thumb = "http://somesite.net/imageurl";
var service = new TwitterService(key, secret);
service.AuthenticateWith(token, tokenSecret);
var req = WebRequest.Create(thumb);
using (var stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    response = service.SendTweetWithMedia(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions
    {
    Status = tweet.Trim(),
    Images = new Dictionary<string, Stream> { { fullname, stream } }
    });
}
```

A GIF may fail during Tweet creation even if it is [within the file size limit](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media). Adhere to the following constraints to improve success rates.

1. Resolution should be <= 1280x1080 (width x height)
2. Number of frames <= 350
3. Number of pixels (width * height * num_frames) <= 300 million
4. Filesize <= 15Mb

Comment: I completely missed that! Thanks a lot. Now I'm getting another error. Its posting the image perfectly now, but if the image is to large, "result" comes out as Null (A error occurred), it throws a NullRefrenceException. How could I error check this? I tried a Try/Catch block but it didnt work.